# “alias android-disconnect=”fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus”

Tags: sudo, alias, su

I dont think this is a big deal but it has been annoying me for the past month and im a newbie to linux and im learning it at the moment,

everytime i do `Sudo -i` or `Su "Username"` it actually logs in to the root but it gives me this message with no errors

```
“alias android-disconnect=”fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus”
```

How can i fix this please?

Comment: Look in `/home/username/.bashrc` that's where the error is coming from and it should be `alias android-disconnect='fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus'`

Comment: As George says, I think the message is indicating that your .bashrc file doesn't understand that line. George points out that the double quotes " should be replaced with single quotes '. That alias, by the way, means that if you type android-disconnect at the command line, the command 'fusermount -u /media/GalaxyNexus' will be run.

Comment: Okay so the problem was that there was an "echo" command behind that line in the ~/.bashrc , i removed the "echo" because it turned out the command needs to run from alias not echo alias .